# ctrl+c not working in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2

Really weird problem.

in iTerm2 only, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> no longer work to kill the running program (Terminal is fine).

I've looked into the settings, but I can't see anything that might be causing this. What could be the problem..?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into same problem

Comment: No, sorry--I've seen moved to Linux and it does work here.

Comment: For anyone still looking for an answer, please [take a look here](https://superuser.com/a/1319732/111429).

Comment: Running `reset` worked for me. The terminal printed out `Interrupt set to control-C (^C).
` and ctrl-c worked fine.